# Como fazer tradução no código java?

Tags: java, android

Na aplicação Android tem como traduzir as string xml. Como faço isso no código java?

Nesse código, por exemplo:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando o aplicativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem o arquivo **res/values/strings.xml**, correto?

Então você deve criar um novo diretório **values** referente a linguagem que quer usar no APP, por exemplo:

- res/values-fr/strings.xml
- res/values-ja/strings.xml

E no Toast, ao invés de colocar o texto direto ali, você puxaria de **R.string.carregando** por exemplo

Irá funcionar de acordo com a linguagem padrão do device do usuário, se o device dele estiver configurado pra Francês, o Java automáticamente irá se encarregar de ir buscar os textos em **res/values-fr/strings.xml**

Comment: Muito bem explicado. Deu certo, muito obrigado!